# Ubuntu 19.04 stuck at boot after installing legacy nvidia 340 driver

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I'm new to Linux. I've installed Ubuntu 19.04.
Everything went perfectly, except for display driver.

If I install my display driver ( Nvidia 340 legacy )

And reboot, I can't boot my OS anymore. I can't even get to login screen. It will just stuck when it says

(   [  OK  ] Started gnome display manager )

I thought first it's because of the [ Gnome display manager ]

But I don't think that's the case. As I've installed antergos with latest gnome stack 3.32. Everything was perfect. But I love Ubuntu. And now after this new release I love it more..

Sorry for my bad English. Any help is appreciated

EDIT: After digging around. I found that this issue is actually not related to Nvidia. In fact this happen if I disable nouveau driver... Any suggestions?

Comment: I never had much luck with `340` driver with my old GTX 630M. Now with the GTX 970M I find the `384` driver so stable and fast I don't feel any need to upgrade whatsoever. What nvidia card do you have?

Comment: I have nvidia geforce 315M

Comment: Oh that must be old. What kind of CPU?

Comment: Index. It's an old laptop. Lol.. Anyways. CPU is intel core i3-2350M 2.30 GHz x 4. Ubuntu 18.04.2 works fine.

Comment: Well well. After digging around. I found that this issue is actually not related to Nvidia. In fact this happen if I disable nouveau driver... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well. Found a temporary fix.  I turn on my laptop and after the bios screen and before Ubuntu logo. I kept pressing [ ESC ] multiple times  until it shows me Ubuntu logo and splash screen. Then quickly press [ ALT + F2 and then F1 quickly ] it will work

Comment: :)) what kind of error and how to fix?